# how get tags from a XElement

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, azure-blob-storage

I've developed code like this:

```
String resultString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
Stream resultStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

XElement rootElement = XDocument.Load(resultStream).Elements().First();
XElement blobs = rootElement.Element("Blobs");
foreach (var blob in blobs.Elements("Blob"))
{
    var t = blob;
}
```

Now the `resultString` and `resultStream` come from `HttpClient reposnse`. I get the response from an Azure blob REST service (listing), like this:

```
<EnumerationResults>
    <Blobs>
        <Blob>
            <Name></Name>
            <Url></Url>
            <Properties></Properties>
         </Blob>
         <Blob>
            <Name></Name>
            <Url></Url>
            <Properties></Properties>
         </Blob>
    </Blobs>
</EnumerationResults>
```

With my code, I've managed to get an `IEnumerable<XNode>` from `<Blobs>` BUT I can't get to `Name` and `Url` inside the `<Blob>` element. I get all of it as a string in one line. How do I need to change my code to get each `<Blob>` and get from it `<Name>` and `<Url>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to start with, once you've loaded the document, you can just use the `Root` property to get at the root element. You can then get each `Blob` element using `Descendants` or via multiple calls to `Elements`. You can do that *outside* the `foreach` loop though:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(resultStream);
var allBlobs = doc.Root.Elements("Blobs").Elements("Blob");
```

or
    var doc = XDocument.Load(resultStream);
    var allBlobs = doc.Root.Descendants("Blob");

Now when you iterate over each blob, you can just get the name element using `Element` again, and get the text content of the element by using the explicit string conversion

```
foreach (var blob in allBlobs)
{
    var nameElement = blob.Element("Name");
    var nameText = (string) nameElement;
    ...
}
```

Obviously that can be done as a single statement - I just wanted to keep them separate for clarity. You can then do the same for the URL. Using the string conversion gives you a `null` reference if the element is missing, whereas using the `Value` property will give you a `NullReferenceException` unless you guard against it. Which is more appropriate depends on your use case.

An alternative approach is to do all the extraction *outside* your `foreach` loop, in a query:

```
var data = doc.Root.Elements("Blobs").Elements("Blob")
              .Select(blob => new {
                  Name = (string) blob.Element("Name"),
                  Url = (string) blob.Element("Url");
              });
```

Then:

```
foreach (var item in data)
{
    // Use item.Name and item.Data in here
}
```

Comment: I usually use `Descendants` instead of `Elements`, are there any fundamental differences for my own sake?

Comment: @LukeHennerley: Absolutely - Descendants will find the elements *anywhere*, whereas using Elements documents where you expect to find them, and won't return elements which occur in other locations. If everything's where you expect it to be, they're the same, of course...

Comment: `Descendants` is lazy in a way then, that it will search across all `Elements` from the top down. So `elements` in this scope, would be more appropriate. Thanks for clearing that up for me :)

Answer (score 0):

```
XElement blobs = rootElement.Element("Blobs");
var v = blobs.Select(blob => new { Name = blob.Descendents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Name"), Url = blob.Descendants.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Url") });
```